# Similar Image Searching by Metric Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a program that show top 3 of similar image to query image, using python.

I thought Siamese Network by Triplet Loss can be good option for what I want to do.

I wrote some codes and created model with small dataset in my pc. And I inputted one of the dataset into the program to evaluate my program. I expected that the program would show same image as what I input, but the program doesn't always do so.

For example, there are five images, A, B, C, D and E. I created a model which learned the five images with Siamese Network by Triplet Loss and saved the model. And I loaded the model and input the image B for prediction, expecting that the program return B as a result, but it returns D.
When comparison of distance between dataset and query follows model training, results are as I expected. (Input Image A and return Image A)
However, after model training completed, when I load trained model and try to predict, it doesn't return correctly.

Did I do something wrong in model structure?
Or Siamese Network is not appropriate for my problem?

If structure of my code is not so bad, I guess it should be an issue of quality of the dataset.

My program is as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler, ModelCheckpoint, History
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import datetime
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances, roc_auc_score

import load_dataset2_1 as ld

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def create_resnet(size, channel, num_classes):
    input_tensor = layers.Input((size, size, channel))
    ResNet50 = resnet.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False, pooling="avg")
    embedding_model = Sequential()
    embedding_model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=ResNet50.output_shape[1:]))
    embedding_model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    embedding_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    embedding_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    embedding_model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes))
    embedding_model = Model(inputs=ResNet50.input, outputs=embedding_model(ResNet50.output))
    embedding_model.summary()
    
    trainable = False
    for layer in ResNet50.layers:
        if layer.name == "conv5_block1_out":
            trainable = True
        layer.trainable = trainable
    
    return embedding_model

def create_concatenate_layer(embedding_model, size, channel):
    input_anchor = layers.Input(shape=(size, size, channel))
    input_positive = layers.Input(shape=(size, size, channel))
    input_negative = layers.Input(shape=(size, size, channel))
    
    embedding_anchor = embedding_model(input_anchor)
    embedding_positive = embedding_model(input_positive)
    embedding_negative = embedding_model(input_negative)
    
    output = layers.concatenate([embedding_anchor, embedding_positive,embedding_negative])
    net = Model([input_anchor, input_positive, input_negative], output)
    return net
    
    
# Online Triplet
def triplet_loss(label, embeddings):
    
    x1 = tf.expand_dims(embeddings, axis=0)
    x2 = tf.expand_dims(embeddings, axis=1)
    euclidean = tf.reduce_sum((x1-x2)**2, axis=-1)
    
    lb1 = tf.expand_dims(label[:, 0], axis=0)
    lb2 = tf.expand_dims(label[:, 0], axis=1)
    equal_mat = tf.equal(lb1, lb2)
    
    # positives
    positive_ind = tf.where(equal_mat)
    positive_dists = tf.gather_nd(euclidean, positive_ind)
    print("positive_ind : ", positive_ind)
    print("positive_dists : ", positive_dists)
    
    # negatives
    negative_ind = tf.where(tf.logical_not(equal_mat))
    negative_dists = tf.gather_nd(euclidean, negative_ind)
    
    print("negative_ind : ", positive_ind)
    print("negative_dists : ", positive_dists)
    
    
    # [P, N]
    margin = 0.25
    positives = tf.expand_dims(positive_dists, axis=1)
    negatives = tf.expand_dims(negative_dists, axis=0)
    triplets = tf.maximum(positives - negatives + margin, 0.0)
    return tf.reduce_mean(triplets)
    
    
def create_batch(x_train, y_train, size, channel, batch_size):
    x_anchors = np.zeros((batch_size, size, size, channel))
    x_positives = np.zeros((batch_size, size, size, channel))
    x_negatives = np.zeros((batch_size, size, size, channel))
    
    for i in range(0, batch_size):
        random_index = random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0]-1)
        x_anchor = x_train[random_index]
        y = y_train[random_index]
        
        dogs_for_pos = np.squeeze(np.where(y_train==y))
        dogs_for_neg = np.squeeze(np.where(y_train!=y))
        
        # print("len(dogs_for_pos) : ", len(dogs_for_pos))
        # print("len(dogs_for_neg) : ", len(dogs_for_neg))
        
        x_positive = x_train[dogs_for_pos[random.randint(0, len(dogs_for_pos)-1)]]
        x_negative = x_train[dogs_for_neg[random.randint(0, len(dogs_for_neg)-1)]]

        x_anchors[i] = x_anchor
        x_positives[i] = x_positive
        x_negatives[i] = x_negative

    print("x_anchors.shape___", x_anchors.shape)
    print("x_positives.shape___", x_positives.shape)
    print("x_negatives.shape___", x_negatives.shape)
    
    return [x_anchors, x_positives, x_negatives]
    

def data_generator(x_train, y_train, size, channel, batch_size, emb_size):
    
    while True:
        x = create_batch(x_train, y_train, size, channel, batch_size)
        y = np.zeros((batch_size, 3*emb_size))
        yield x, y
        


def train_generator(X, y_label, batch_size):
    while True:
        indices = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
        for i in range(len(indices)//batch_size):
            current_indices = indices[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            X_batch = X[current_indices] / 255.0
            y_batch = np.zeros((batch_size, 128), np.float32)
            y_batch[:, 0] = y_label[current_indices]
            yield X_batch, y_batch


def step_decay(epoch):
    x = 1e-3
    if epoch >= 25: x /= 10.0
    if epoch >= 45: x /= 10.0
    return x
    
size = 128
channel = 3
batch_size = 64
epochs = 1000
emb = 64


    
def train(folder, size=size, batch_size=batch_size, channel=channel, epochs=epochs):
    print("TensorFlow version: ", tf.__version__)
    print("folder : ", folder)
    print("size : {0}, batch_size : {1}, channel : {2}, epochs : {3}".format(size, batch_size, channel, epochs))
    switch = input("Load data : On or Off: ")
    if switch == "On" or switch == "ON" or switch == "on":
        switch = "On"
        size = ''
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test), size = ld.main(switch, folder)
        x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], size, size, channel))/255.0
        x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], size, size, channel))/255.0
        # print('num_files: ', num_files)
    num_classes=len(os.listdir(folder))
    steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0]//batch_size
    # opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1e-3, 0.9)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("./triplet_model/model_dbt_2.hdf5", monitor="loss", save_best_only=True, save_weight_only=True)
    # es_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0.0001, patience=3, mode='auto')
    net = create_resnet(size, channel, 256)
    
    net.summary()
    net.compile(loss=triplet_loss, metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt)
    
    # hist = net.fit(data_generator(x_train, y_train, size, channel, batch_size, emb_size=emb), 
    #     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
    #     # validation_data = (x_test, y_test), 
    #     callbacks=[checkpoint, scheduler]
    # )
    
    hist = net.fit_generator(train_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size), 
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
        # validation_data = train_generator(x_test, y_test, batch_size), 
        callbacks=[checkpoint, scheduler],
        max_queue_size = 1
    )
    
    
    
    
    net.save("./triplet_model/new_model.h5")
    net.save("./triplet_model/new_model")
    net.save_weights("./triplet_model/new_weights.hdf5", save_format="h5")
    
    x = range(epochs)
    plt.title("Model accuracy")
    plt.plot(x, hist.history["accuracy"], label="accuracy")
    plt.plot(x, hist.history["loss"], label="loss")
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), borderaxespad=0, ncol=2)
    
    name="resnet_dogs_trian_result {0} {1}h-{2}m-{3}s.jpg".format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
    plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()
    
    
def main(test_img, folder="Base_dogs_2", base_folder="Base_dogs"):

    num_files = len(os.listdir(base_folder))
    # model = create_resnet(size, channel, 256)

    if not os.path.isfile("./triplet_model/model_dbt_2.hdf5") and not os.path.isfile("./triplet_model/new_weights.hdf5"):

        train(folder=folder)
        # train(folder="Base_dogs_2")

    if os.path.isfile("./triplet_model/model_dbt_2.hdf5"):
        print("Loading weights: 'model_dbt_2.hdf5'")
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./triplet_model/new_model.h5", custom_objects={'triplet_loss' : triplet_loss})
        model.load_weights("./triplet_model/model_dbt_2.hdf5")
        # model.summary()
    
    elif os.path.isfile("./triplet_model/new_weights.hdf5"):
        print("Loading weights: 'new_weights.hdf5'")
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./triplet_model/new_model.h5", custom_objects={'triplet_loss' : triplet_loss})
        model.load_weights("./triplet_model/new_weights.hdf5")
    
    else:
        print("Cannot load weights")
    
    X_base=[]
    Y=[]
    bbb=0
    #db = Dogs.objects.all()
    db = os.listdir(base_folder)
    print("db : ", db)
    for b_img in db:
        bbb += 1
        file_name = b_img
        b_img = base_folder + "/" + b_img
        print("img_path : ", b_img)
        
        bmg = Image.open(b_img)
        bmg.show()
        bmg.save("{0}{1}.jpg".format(bbb, file_name))
        # bmg = bmg.convert("L")
        bmg = bmg.resize((size, size))
        b_data = np.asarray(bmg)
        X_base.append(b_data)
        Y.append(b_img)
    
    X_base = np.array(X_base)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    
    print("X_base.shape : ", X_base.shape)
    print("Y.shape : ", Y.shape)
    
    label_ec = LabelEncoder()
    label = label_ec.fit_transform(Y)
    
    X_base = X_base.astype(np.float32)
    # X_base = tf.expand_dims(X_base, axis=-1)
    print("X_base.shape after expand_dims : ", X_base.shape)
    
    (x_base, y_base) = (X_base, label)
    
    file = test_img
    print("test_img : ", file)
    X=[]
    
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.show()
    # img = img.convert("L")
    img = img.resize((size, size))
    data = np.asarray(img)
    X.append(data)
    X = np.array(X)
    X = X.astype(np.float32)
    X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], size, size, channel))/255.0
    
    print("X.shape : ", X.shape)
    
    
    #X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
    
    anchor_embedding = model.predict(x_base, verbose=1)
    test_embedding = model.predict(X, verbose=1)
    
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((test_embedding.shape[0], anchor_embedding.shape[0]), np.float32)
    print("dist_matrix.shape : ", dist_matrix.shape)
    
    for i in range(dist_matrix.shape[0]):
        dist_matrix[i, :] = euclidean_distances(test_embedding[i, :].reshape(1, -1), anchor_embedding)[0]
    
    print("dist_matrix : ", dist_matrix)
    
    #distance against query image
    min_dist = np.min(dist_matrix, axis=-1)
    min_idx = np.argmin(dist_matrix)
    print("min_dist : ", min_dist)
    print("min_idx : ", min_idx)
    
    print("base_file_name : ", db)
    time = "{0} {1}h-{2}m-{3}s_{4}".format(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), now.hour, now.minute, now.second, base_folder)
    print("file_name : time__", time)
    results_path = []
    path = 'static/results_'
    
    # print("x_base[min_idx] : ", x_base[min_idx])
    pil_img_1 = np.reshape(x_base[min_idx], (size, size, channel))
    print("pil_img_1.shape : ", pil_img_1.shape)
    pil_img_1 = Image.fromarray(pil_img_1.astype(np.uint8))
    results_path_1 = '{0}{1}_1.jpg'.format(path, time)
    pil_img_1.save(results_path_1)
    results_path.append(str(results_path_1))
    
    
    min_dist_2 = np.min(dist_matrix[dist_matrix > min_dist], axis=-1)
    print("min_dist_2 : ", min_dist_2)
    print("np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_2)) : ",np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_2)))
    min_idx_2 = np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_2))[1]
    print("min_idx_2 : ", min_idx_2)
    
    img_2 = np.reshape(x_base[min_idx_2], (size, size, channel))
    pil_img_2 = Image.fromarray(img_2.astype(np.uint8))
    results_path_2 = '{0}{1}_2.jpg'.format(path, time)
    pil_img_2.save(results_path_2)
    results_path.append(str(results_path_2))
    
    
    min_dist_3 = np.min(dist_matrix[dist_matrix > min_dist_2], axis=-1)
    print("min_dist_3___", min_dist_3)
    min_idx_3 = np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_3))[1]
    print("np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_3)) : ",np.squeeze(np.where(dist_matrix==min_dist_3)))
    print("min_idx_3___", min_idx_3)

    img_3 = np.reshape(x_base[min_idx_3], (size, size, channel))
    pil_img_3 = Image.fromarray(img_3.astype(np.uint8))
    results_path_3 = '{0}{1}_3.jpg'.format(path, time)
    pil_img_3.save(results_path_3)
    results_path.append(str(results_path_3))


    print(results_path)
    
    dist_matrix = np.empty(0)
    print("dist_matrix after clear : ", dist_matrix)
    
    
    
    return results_path # return top 3 similar images


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = "A.jpg"
    b_fn = "test"
    result = main(test_img=t)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Its a lot to look through and debug, but wouldn't an easier option to start with be using structural similarity index(SSIM)?

Comment: Maybe an autoencoder would be better suited for this problem instead of a siamese network, and it would also simplify the code a lot.

Comment: I didn't know autoencoder and SSIM. Will study and try with it. And basically, if I want to use Siamese network, I just load model and weight after training model. Is this understanding correct? Or do I need to train model every time I predict something by Siamese network? Thank you so much for your comments and answers.